# Import DynamoDB Table - YML

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have a serverless yml file for node project with aws. Also I have a dynamodb table in another file. I can deploy the project with no issues, however VSCode is showing a red alert problem in my import line: Incorrect type expected...

serverless.yml

```
service: auction-service

plugins:
  - serverless-bundle
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  memorySize: 256
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: eu-west-1
  environment:
    AUCTIONS_TABLE_NAME: ${self:custom.AuctionsTable.name}
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - ${file(iam/AuctionsTableIAM.yml):AuctionsTableIAM}

resources:
  Resources:
    AuctionsTable: ${file(resources/AuctionsTable.yml):AuctionsTable}

functions:
  createAuction:
    handler: src/handlers/createAuction.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: POST
          path: /auction

custom:
  AuctionsTable:
    name: !Ref AuctionsTable
    arn: !GetAtt AuctionsTable.Arn
  bundle:
    linting: false
```

AuctionsTable.yml:

```
[![AuctionsTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: AuctionsTable--${self:provider.stage}
    BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: id
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: id
        KeyType: HASH][1]][1]
```

[image: Error capture][image: Error Capture]

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
resources:
  Resources:
    - ${file(resources/AuctionsTable.yml):AuctionsTable}
```

Note, you will need to add the name `AuctionsTable` to the imported file.

Comment: Hello @Gwed, thank you for the response, I tried that with the same result. The deployment is working fine, is just that red warning the one that is still active.